# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS: Value too large for defined data type

Tags: ubuntu, size, data

I am trying to run Partiview software which is a visualization tool for particle data sets. I have run a large simulation that includes millions of particles and the resultant data file that I am attempting to visualize is 4.26 GB. When I attempt to run the software, I get the following error:

```
./partiview sim_evo_128_snap50.cf 
./leigh_data/dm128_evolution_50snap.speck: can't open: Value too large for defined data type
```

My understanding is that the default maximum size is 2GB for a 32-bit system, and I need to change the system settings for a 64-bit system for larger files. How exactly do I accomplish this in the terminal, and is 4GB the maximum size for a data file in a 64-bit system?

Comment: (1). You can't "change the system settings for a 64-bit system". To go from a 32-bit system to a 64-bit system you would need to reinstall completely. (2). The file size on a 32-bit system is not necessarily constrained to the relatively small sizes of 2GB or 4GB. It depends on the filesystem. FAT32 has a small file size limit. The extN filesystems do not.

Comment: I am on a 64-bit system while getting this error. Is there anything I can do to work with a file of this size?

Comment: What's the relevance of this reference to a 32-bit system, then? « _My understanding is that the default maximum size is 2GB for a 32-bit system_ »

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message you get matches the error code `EOVERFLOW`, which in the [`open` system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) is returned if a 32-bit application tries to open a large (>= 2 GB) file:

> EOVERFLOW
>           pathname  refers  to  a regular file that is too large to be
>           opened.  The usual scenario here is that an application compiled
>           on a 32-bit platform without -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 tried to open
>           a file whose size exceeds (1<<31)-1 bytes;

As the text hints, 32-bit applications can access larger files, iff they are compiled with the necessary settings (using larger integers for the relevant data types, and calling the proper versions of the system calls).

It would seem that the application you are running isn't compiled to support large files. And no, you can't change that except by recompiling it or getting a version with large file support.